# The AggregateException I catch does not have the exception I expect

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I am using the Task Parallel Library to set up a chain of Tasks as shown below but I am getting an odd exception handling experience that I don't understand.

I use Parallel.ForEach and invoke an Action which includes a call to the following method. This Parallel.ForEach is wrapped in a try...catch(AggregateException) and when an exception occurs - as it does in one of the Parallel branches - a SchemaValidation exception then I would expect to see that in the AggregateException.

However, what I get is 'A task was canceled' - TaskCanceledException. Where has my SchemaValidationException gone?

```
        private static void ProcessChunk(Task<ISelectedChunk> selectionTask, 
                                     IRepository repository, 
                                     IIdentifiedExtractChunk identifiedExtractChunk, 
                                     IBatchRunConfiguration batchRunConfiguration, 
                                     IBatchRun batchRun, 
                                     ILog log, 
                                     IAuthenticationCertificate authenticationCertificate, 
                                     IFileSystem fileSystem,
                                     long batchRunRid)
    {
        var transformationTask = selectionTask.ContinueWith(TransformationFunction.Transformation(identifiedExtractChunk, batchRunConfiguration, batchRun),
                                                            TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

        var schemaValidationTask = transformationTask.ContinueWith(SchemaValidationFunction.SchemaValidationTask(batchRunConfiguration),
                                                                   TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

        var compressTask = schemaValidationTask.ContinueWith(CompressFunction.CompressTask(identifiedExtractChunk),
                                                             TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

        var encryptTask = compressTask.ContinueWith(EncryptionFunction.EncryptTask(authenticationCertificate),
                                                    TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

        var fileGenerationTask = encryptTask.ContinueWith(FileGenerationFunction.FileGenerationTask(identifiedExtractChunk, batchRunConfiguration, fileSystem),
                                                          TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
        // Take the time before we start the processing
        DateTime startBatchItemProcessing = DateTime.Now;

        // Start with the Selection Task
        selectionTask.Start();

        // And wait on the last task in the chain
        fileGenerationTask.Wait();

        // Take the time at the end of the processing
        DateTime endBatchItemProcessing = DateTime.Now;

        // Record all the relevant information and add it to the collection 
        IBatchChunkProcessed batchChunkProcessed = GetBatchItemProcessed(identifiedExtractChunk, batchRunRid, fileGenerationTask.Result, transformationTask.Result.Item2, startBatchItemProcessing, endBatchItemProcessing);
        BatchItemsProcessed.Add(batchChunkProcessed);
```

Comment: Why are you even using `Task`s here? Why don't you just execute all the methods sequentially?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.  Post the code that catches and processes the exception.

Comment: @svick -The selection task passed in is parallelised. Also, these are discrete building block tasks that could easily be re-used - and possibly made the root task - in other contexts.

Comment: @HansPassant - the problem is not with the exception handling code - no matter where I put that I got the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's simplify your code a bit:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(a1);
var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(a2, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
var t3 = t2.ContinueWith(a3, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

t3.Wait();
```

Now assume that `a1` throws an exception. What happens is that `t1` becomes faulted (`t1.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted`). Because of that, `t2` can't run (because of `NotOnFaulted`) and so it will be canceled. But this is not what you presumably expected: `t2` won't be faulted, it will be canceled (`t2.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled`). But this means that `t3` can run normally, and if it doesn't throw, `t3.Wait()` won't throw any exception.

How to fix this? First, you probably shouldn't use `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted`, but `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` instead. But that doesn't solve the problem of “disappearing” exceptions. To solve that, I see two possibilities:

1. Call `Wait()` at the beginning of each continuation and don't use any `TaskContinuationOptions`. This means you might get some exception wrapped in `AggregateException`, which is itself wrapped in `AggregateException`, which is wrapped in another `AggregateException`, etc. To solve this, you could use [`Flatten()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten.aspx) or [`Handle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle.aspx).
2. Wait for all the tasks, by using [`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx). `WaitAll()` will throw an `AggregateException` that will contain the original exception and also `TaskCanceledException` for each of the tasks that were canceled because of the first exception.

Comment: I went for the Task.WaitAll option - seemed like the cleanest. I now get the exceptions I want as well as the TaskCanceledExceptions. Many thanks.